# Migrations were shown as down but already migrated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

I've rails app that has some migrations. When I hit `rake db:migrate:status` to see what status is set, all except `********** NO FILE **********` were down. But the migrations have already made, so there seems no problem about model side. Here are files may help to explain:

Output of `rake db:migrate:status`:

```
 up     20130727003912  ********** NO FILE **********
down    20130728000151  Devise create users
down    20130728000335  Create friends
down    20130728000346  Create addresses
down    20130728000356  Create authies
down    20130728000413  Add indexes
```

At this time, `rake db:migrate` output:

```
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq1" for serial column "users.id"
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "username" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying(255), "reset_password_sent_at" timestamp, "remember_created_at" timestamp, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at" timestamp, "last_sign_in_at" timestamp, "current_sign_in_ip" character varying(255), "last_sign_in_ip" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL) /home/ekrem/workspace/contactman/db/migrate/20130728000151_devise_create_users.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`db/schema.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130727003912) do

  create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "address"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "city"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "country"
  end

  add_index "addresses", ["friend_id"], :name => "index_addresses_on_friend_id"
  add_index "addresses", ["slug"], :name => "index_addresses_on_slug", :unique => true

  create_table "authies", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "authies", ["user_id"], :name => "index_authies_on_user_id"

  create_table "friends", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "surname"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
    t.string   "slug"
    t.string   "imported_file_name"
    t.string   "imported_content_type"
    t.integer  "imported_file_size"
    t.datetime "imported_updated_at"
  end

  add_index "friends", ["slug"], :name => "index_friends_on_slug", :unique => true
  add_index "friends", ["user_id"], :name => "index_friends_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

end
```

How can I fix this issue to make all migrations seem up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your users tables is already created in your database but your schema migration is not updated with latest migration. I dont no why it has not been updated. You need to fix it then you can do it in two ways 1. drop the database and create one more or 2. run the down migration then up migration

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I'm proud to say: 'It Works!'

Answer (score 1):

You can set force to true:

```
create_table :users, force: true do
   ...
end
```

in your migration and delete the migration key in your "schema_migrations" table by hand and rerun the migration.

Answer (score 0):

this worked perfectly for me:

```sh
rails db:drop
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
```

You will notice that the file `developmen.sqlite3` was removed and created again and now everything will be up and running `rails db:migrate:status`